# How to guarantee one function runs after another in the Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

Basically, I want to upload some images before I run other functions that rely on the image being uploaded. I think I may have a misunderstanding of what GCD is/how the threads work. I want function 1 and 2 to happen AFTER I upload the images. They are both quick to execute but rely heavily on the upload images to be complete. Maybe I shouldn't use GCD (as I want to implement a waiting indicator)? I just can't seem to get this to execute properly

```
        if goToHome {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    self.uploadImages() // Uploads the images, takes a good amount of time to execute
                    function1()
                    function2()


                }
            }
```

Functions 1 and 2 keep running before the upload images get completed as they take much less time to execute.

Comment: take a look at `semaphore` in swift. https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb

Comment: A `DispatchGroup` would work well. Also, don't use `sync` on the main queue.

Comment: @Don In this example, `sync` is blocking the `async` queue from running until the block dispatched to the `main` queue returns.  So this is ok.  What you don't want to do is dispatch a block synchronously _from_ the main queue to an async queue.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks @par

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic pattern in Swift is to do work such as uploading on a background thread, then call a completion function on the main thread and continue work based on whether or not your upload finished successfully.

Generally you'll call back onto the main thread in case you need to do something with the user interface such as setting a progress indicator (which has to happen on the main thread).

So something like this:

```
func uploadInBackground(_ images: [Image], completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        var success = true

        // upload the images but stop on any error
        for image in images {
            success = uploadImage(image) // upload your images somehow

            guard success else { break }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(success)
        }
   }
}

func mainThreadUploader() {
    let images = [Image(), Image()] // get your images from somewhere

    // we are on the main thread where UI operations are ok, so:
    startProgressIndicator()

    uploadInBackground(images) { success in
        // this callback is called on the main thread, so:
        stopProgressIndicator()

        guard success else { return }

        // images uploaded ok, so proceed with functions that depend on
        // the upload(s) completing successfully:
        function1()
        function2()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite running the upload image function in the main queue, the upload image function itself is running operations in a background queue. To fix this, possible strategies would be:

- use a completion handler with the image upload, likely the easiest to implement depending on the implementation of the `self.uploadImages()` function
- make the image uploading happen on the main thread, which is likely hard to implement and inadvisable
- use a dispatch group, which I personally have less experience with but is an option

Comment: Ah I see, I had super confused on the why that was happening but now it makes sense.